# Who is Dasharha? And why is Krishna referred to as belonging to Dasharha's race?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, chandravansh, yadavas

At [a few places](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.sacred-texts.com%2Fhin%20ashvatthama&oq=site%3Awww.sacred-texts.com%2Fhin%20ashvatthama&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.378j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.sacred-texts.com%2Fhin%20dasharha) in The Mahabharata, Sri Krishna is referred to as 'he of **Dasharha**'s race.'

Who is Dasharha and how is Krishna related to him?

Dictionary [meaning](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=dazArha&direction=SE&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=) for the word just says 'Krishna.'

> The Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva:
>
> And consoling Yudhishthira, Krishna set out for Dwaraka on his car resplendent as the sun and unto which were yoked the horses Saivya and Sugriva. And after **he of the Dasharha race had departed**, Dhristadyumna, the son of Prishata, also set out for his own city, taking with him the sons of Draupadi. And the king of Chedi, Dhrishtaketu also, taking his sister with him set out for his beautiful city of Suktimati, after bidding farewell to the Pandavas. And, O Bharata, the Kaikeyas also, with the permission of Kunti's son possessed of immeasurable energy, having reverentially saluted all the Pandavas, went away. But Brahmanas and the Vaisyas and the dwellers of Yudhishthira's kingdom though repeatedly requested to go, did not leave the Pandavas. O foremost of king, O bull of the Bharata race, the multitude that surrounded those high-souled ones in the forest of Kamyaka looked extraordinary. And Yudhishthira, honouring those high-minded Brahmanas, in due time ordered his men, saying 'Make ready the car.'
>
> The Mahabharata, Book 8: Karna Parva: Section 59:
>
> Meanwhile the driver of Drona's son, beholding the latter senseless, quickly bore him away on his car from the field of battle. Beholding Prishata's son rescued and Drona's son afflicted, the Pancalas, O king, expectant of victory, began to utter loud shouts. Thousands of sweet instruments began to be sounded. Seeing such wonderful feats in battle, the combatants uttered leonine roars. Having achieved that feat, Partha addressed Vasudeva, saying "Proceed, O Krishna, towards the *samsaptakas*, for this is greatly desired by me." Hearing those words of Pandu's son, **he of Dasharha's race** proceeded on that car graced with many banners and whose speed resembled that of the wind or the mind.'

Comment: Upon Google, your Q appears 1st for `Dasharha`! Really less info on internet.

Comment: @iammilind [Puranic Encyclopedia](http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Puranas/Puranic_Encyclopedia.htm) is good site to search.

Comment: @Surya Btw `Dasharhaa` is also one of the 1000 names mentioned in VishnuSahastranaama. It comes as `Dasharhaa Saatvatam Pati`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dasharha is the descendant of Yadu. He is the son of Nivrti and grandson of Vrshni, as is retold in [Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/24/3-4) 9th Canto 24th Chapter 3rd Sloka.

> krathasya kuntiḥ putro ’bhūd 
> vṛṣṇis tasyātha nirvṛtiḥ 
> **tato daśārho nāmnābhūt** 
> tasya vyomaḥ sutas tataḥ
>
> The son of Kratha was Kunti; the son of Kunti, Vṛṣṇi; the son of Vṛṣṇi, Nirvṛti; **and the son of Nirvṛti, Daśārha**. From Daśārha came Vyoma...

Since Dasharha was a prominent King, the Yadavas were also called Daasharhas or descendants of Dasharha.